# Flutter expandable list tree

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

How to implement this expandable list tree using flutter? Please recommend if you know any related packages.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `flutter_fancy_tree_view` pacakge
[this link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_fancy_tree_view)